# jQuery.ajax does not return data

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I've been trying to query a MySQL database for a single row using `jQuery.ajax`. The `$.ajax` call is apparently not succeeding because the data arrays' values are "undefined" and the alert I inserted is not appearing.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

```
function getdata(j) {
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'get-wx.php', 
  data: "date=" + picdate + "&time=" + pictime + "00",  
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(wxdata)
  {

alert ("success");      

    wx_date[j] = wxdata[1];
    wx_time[j] = wxdata[2];
    wx_temp[j] = wxdata[6];
  }
});
}
```

I've tested my PHP script and it returns what appears to be valid json encoded data from the database:

`["site_wx","2015-03-22","09:12:34","0","135","0","49.6","76","29.84","0","0","0","0","0","59.4","48","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","9","12","34","","0","0","22","3","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","49.6","0","0","0","0","","0","0","42.4","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]`

Comment: Do you get any particular error message on your browser console?

Comment: Also, in the web console I can see the php call and response with the json data.

Comment: I don't see any errors.

Comment: Try using `.done(function( data ) {...});` per [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: Have you tried adding a question mark at the start of the data attribute? `"?date=" + picdate + "&time=" + pictime + "00"`

Comment: CosX: Thanks. That didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Phil: Thanks for the response, but I'm having trouble understanding what that would look like.

Comment: Would it go in place of the success: parameter?

Comment: Try using `JSON.parse(wxdata)` and then use `wxdata[1]...`

Comment: try to send data like this `data: { "date": picdate, "time": pictime + "00" }`

Comment: I just tried JSON.parse(wxdata) in the success clause, but no change. I think because it's not succeeding for some reason.

Comment: did you try adding an `error:` function to the ajax call to see if it gets invoked?

Comment: The error function is returning "parserror".